# How can I make an array with the values i get from an URL?

Tags: php, wordpress, url

I'm using Gravity Forms on Wordpress to get values from a form, which i configured to send the data via url to a specific page.

I have a shortcode of a plugin on that page and I want to get the data from the url and save it in an array in the function of that shortcode.

Comment: Surley it is already in the `$_GET` array if you put values onto the URL Querystring

Comment: the thing is that I have too many values on the url and i dont want to get those values one by one, that's why i want to know if there's a way to save them all in an array

Comment: `$_GET` IS AN ARRAY

Comment: Ok thanks, I think I know now what to do. Sorry for my ignorance hahah I actually dont know how to code

Comment: Then strictly, you are in the wrong place

Comment: Just to be sure... 
if i have this URL: example.com/?Name=hello

this function should work correctly?

function example() {
    $nombre = $_GET['Name'];
    echo $nombre;
}

Comment: Please never put code in a comment, its almost unreadable as you can see

Comment: Or simply `echo $_GET['Name'];`